# Change Toolbar Background Color and Title

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I am trying to change the `background` and `title` of the `toolbar widget` set as `actionbar`.

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

It want it like the Google Play Store App.  
Apps -> Grey (background) and "Apps" (title) 
My Apps -> Green (background) and "My Apps" (title)

 so i tried already to change the title with

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Jiji");

toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Jiji");
getActivity().setActionBar(toolbar); // error: incompatible types: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to android.widget.Toolbar

getActivity.setTitle("ododo") //works for a short moment
```

for the background there is just a method called `setBackgroundDrawable` marked as `deprecated``but the method don´t work for me :-(
maybe releated https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78471&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

any idea is welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself 
first change `Activity` to `ActionBarActivity` then you can work with getSupportActionBar() for the toolbar background like:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f44336")));
```

and for the statusbar you can work with setStatusBarColor like:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#e53935"));
}
```

cheers ternes3